# ng-click does not fire javascript global function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and I've put an ng-click on a radio button generated by
ng-repeat, and the click event refuses to fire. If I use a simple onclick,
that does work though.

This works, and I see the alert:

```
<div class="span2 left-justify"
        ng-repeat="choice in physicalmode_choices">
    <input type="radio"
            name="physical_layer"
            value="{{ choice.private }}"
            onclick="alert('foo')"
            required
            ng-model="$parent.networkoptions.physicalmode" />
            &nbsp;<span ng-bind="choice.public"></span>
</div>
```

But this does not:

```
<div class="span2 left-justify"
        ng-repeat="choice in physicalmode_choices">
    <input type="radio"
            name="physical_layer"
            value="{{ choice.private }}"
            ng-click="alert('foo')"
            required
            ng-model="$parent.networkoptions.physicalmode" />
            &nbsp;<span ng-bind="choice.public"></span>
</div>
```

Can I not do this with an ng-click? Or am I misunderstanding what an "expression" is?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Consider changing the title of this question, it doesn't describes the problem and its answer. Same problem would happen with any directive or structure, not only this one. Maybe something like *ng-click doesn't recognise native javascript function*

Answer (score 20):

To clarify DerekR's answer.

When angular sees

```
ng-click='alert("test")'
```

it looks for

```
$scope.alert
```

which is likely to be undefined.

You need to provide a proxy method on the scope, or possibly even rootscope.

For example:

```
$rootScope.log = function(variable) {
    console.log(variable);
};
$rootScope.alert = function(text) {
    alert(text);
};
```

See: http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#scopemethods

Answer (score 2):

When you call something inside of an ng-click the parsing service evaluates expressions against the scope rather than the global window object.

If you wanted to do an alert inside of an ng-click then could write a method on the scope or parent scope that in turn calls the alert.

Answer (score 1):

I created this jsFiddle to show how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/tM56a/1/

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in menus" >
     <a ng-click="test(menu)">click me</a>
</li>
```